# Bash : how to find files modified during the current week

Tags: bash

How can I find files modified during the current week (not the last 7 days) - for this week excluding the current day? For example, if today is Wednesday, we need to find the modified files for Tuesday and Monday.

For the last 7 days (excluding current) I can use:

```
find . -name "name_pattern" -mtime +1 -mtime -7
```

However, I am not sure how to do this for the days of the current week, not just the last day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help?

```
for i in {`date +"%u" -d "yesterday"`..1}; do
  date +"%A" -d "$i days ago";
  find . -mtime $i;
  echo "";
done
```

Output:

```
Monday

Tuesday
./.file3
./.file2
Wednesday

Thursday
./.file1
./.file2
```

Comment: This one is working for me, thanks. But instead of using range I used while loop here

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained how this works.

Answer (score 2):

Once way to do this is to get the number of days since last monday. Use `date` command for this:

```
echo $((($(date +%s) - $(date -d 'last mon' +%s))/60/60/24))
```

`+%s` return the number of seconds since `EPOCH` time. So the number needs to be divide to get it into days.

You can then add this to your command:

```
find . -name "name_pattern" -mtime +1 -mtime -$((($(date +%s) - $(date -d 'last mon' +%s))/60/60/24))
```

Answer (score 1):

For Linux we could create temporary files with timestamps. 
For this week excluding the current day it will be:

```
touch -t $(date +"%Y%m%d0000" -d "last mon") ./fromfile
touch -t $(date +"%Y%m%d0000" -d "now")      ./tofile
find . -name "pattern" -newer ./fromfile ! -newer ./tofile
rm ./fromfile ./tofile
```

In Solaris this may be done via some extra programs such perl or python (date command in Solaris will not return correct answer):

```
perl -e 'use Time::Local; use POSIX strftime; 
         my $t=time(); 
         while (strftime("%u",localtime($t)) != 1){ $t -=24*60*60; }; 
         print strftime("%Y%m%d0000",localtime($t) ),"\n";'
```

Code in this perl-example will be the same as 'date +"%Y%m%d0000" -d "last mon"'